# Git/Github strategies in Team when local development not really an option (Shopware)

Tags: github, workflow, shopware

(Background we have 2 Shopware systems one live and dev)

Currently we are using SFTP to upload our files to different Shopware Systems for different Customers. But ofcourse this isn't goood practice and we have no version control at all. So we decided to integrate Git in our Workflow to have some version control. We have on branch for live and dev system. And we are still working with SFTP for the Dev-System and if a Feature is finished we merge it in to the main branch and it gets deployed to the Live-System.

The problem why we can't have local Shopware Systems is because most of the time its customer specific changes which we can only fix on the customers shop. And not on a generic default Shopware Shop. Because of that we can't only use git. We would have to make a commit and push, just to see the changes we made.

Now is this a good workflow? Is it okay to use SFTP?